# Can a decker use multiple cyberdecks?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, sr5-matrix

Could a decker use multiple cyberdecks, each running an Agent, to gain teamwork test dice from more than one agent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes.**

There is nothing in the rules that prevent this. It is expected that the high nuyen cost of cyberdecks provides a significant enough barrier to prevent some enterprising decker from amassing a digital army. Functionally it's no different from a Technomancer being assisted by his Sprites, or a Summoner being assisted by his Spirits. The main difference is Summoners and Technomancers can call forth increasingly smarter and smarter assistants (higher rating Sprites/Spirits), whereas you will always be limited by a maximum rating of 6 for your Agents.